# making a responsive footer with 3 divs inside

Tags: html, css, footer

I want to make a responsive footer with three sections, so one div as the footer than 3 equal size divs in a row within the footer div. I used to use a table with 1 row and 3 columns for this. But I have no idea how to do it with divs and css.

MY CODE SO FAR

```
<div class="push"></div>
    </div>
<div class="footer">
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </div>
```

Thank inadvance

Comment: with divs you use % widths

Comment: check my answer bellow

Comment: Try googling it next time.

Comment: @DaemonOfTheWest I did... there was nothing that I really understood so I hoped this website would help me... but damn are you guys on here rude! I definitely wont be returning... Hopefully one person is nice enough to give me an idea..

Comment: Did you? https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=aligned+divs
That's around ten helpful results on the first page.
We weren't rude. We are simply annoyed that you would waste the time of others instead of googling a basic css technique yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Using % and float

html

```
<div id="footer">
  <div class="footer-section"></div>
  <div class="footer-section"></div>
  <div class="footer-section"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
#footer {
  width:100%; 
}
.footer-section {
  float:left;
  width:33%;
}
```

#### Using display table - [More info](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/)

html

```
<div id="footer">
  <div class="footer-row">
    <div class="footer-section"></div>
    <div class="footer-section"></div>
    <div class="footer-section"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
#footer {
  display:table;
  width:100%;
}
.footer-row {
  display:table-row;
}
.footer-section {
  display:table-cell;
}
```

Comment: thanks soooo much, which way of the two would be the best way in your opinion? Im learning something here :)

Comment: The % option is more popular.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a `%` width for all elements so they will resize when the viewport is resized:

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/0vLbom66/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="footer">
   <div class="section"></div>
   <div class="section"></div>    
   <div class="section"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.footer{
    background: black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 20px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.section{
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
}
```